# Удаление указателей. С++

Tags: c++, указатели, память

```
int main()
{
  int *ptr = new int(5);
  delete ptr;
  // ptr становится висячим указателем.

  std::cout << sizeof(ptr);
  // у меня выводит 4 байта.

  //

  ... какие-то действия в коде

  //
}
```

я обьявляю указатель, который занимает 4 байта у меня в памяти, удаляю его где нибудь в начале тела ( насколько я знаю, delete всего лишь освобождает память, в которой находился указатель ), что происходит с самим указателем ? Почему он до сих пор занимает какую-то память? Это же ведь может влиять на скорость моей программы если я создам сотню указателей, удалю их, а они все равно будут занимать какое - то место.

Comment: С указателем ничего не происходит. освобождается лишь память по адресу, что имеет в своем значении указатель

Comment: Указатель `ptr` - это локальная переменная в функции `main`. Локальную переменную невозможно "удалить". Она сама удалится по завершении блока. `delete`к этому не имеет никакого отношения. Зачем вы сюда приплели этот `delete`?

Comment: Ограничьте область видимости переменной фигурными скобками, и будет вам экономия стека. `void f(){{int*x=..}{int*y=..}{int*z=..}}`. Адреса переменных x,y,z будут одинаковыми.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неправы.

```
delete ptr;
```

освобождает память, **на которую указывает** `ptr`, но никак не место, занимаемое переменной `ptr`.

`sizeof(ptr)` говорит только о том, сколько места в памяти занимает *переменная*, и никак не зависит от ее значения.

На *скорость* программы даже сотня указателей как-то вряд ли повлияет, а вот выделение/освобождение через `new/delete` - может. Именно сам достаточно длительный с точки зрения процессорного времени процесс выделения и освобождения.

Comment: А можно ли удалить саму ptr?

Comment: Если это локальная переменная - нет, пока она не выйдет из области видимости. Если статическая/глобальная (static storage) - то она существует все время работы программы.

Comment: Если статическая, то она будет "жить" до завершения программы? И никак не удалить ?

Comment: Прочитал, просто я писал, и как толЬко отправил, выскочил полностЬю ваш комментарий

Comment: Нет. А зачем, собственно? :) это же в буквальном смысле байты... Если большие куски памяти - массивы, например - то вот их выделяйте через `new`.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но ведь могут же быть случаи, когда нужно освободить место, а у тебя указателей много ( либо так не делают( в смысле не создают много указателей) ). Я вот задумался, что можно ли поудалять указатели

Comment: Много места вы так не освободите. Тем более что это память в стеке - и через `new` она все равно недоступна.

Comment: Подумалось - теоретически вы можете использовать эту память под другие переменные не превышающего размера, путем размещающего `new` или насильственного приведения типа в стиле C - но эта овчинка выделки не стоит...